# R regex find ranges in strings

Tags: regex, r

I have a bunch of email subject lines and I'm trying to extract whether a range of values are present.  This is how I'm trying to do it but am not getting the results I'd like:

```
library(stringi)

df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, string1 = NA)
df1$string1 <- c('15% off','25% off','35% off','45% off','55% off')

df1$pctOff10_20 <- stri_match_all_regex(df1$string1, '[10-20]%')


  id string1 pctOff10_20
1  1 15% off          NA
2  2 25% off          NA
3  3 35% off          NA
4  4 45% off          NA
5  5 55% off          NA
```

I'd like something like this:

```
 id string1 pctOff10_20
1  1 15% off          1
2  2 25% off          0
3  3 35% off          0
4  4 45% off          0
5  5 55% off          0
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, your solution works but with `stri_count_regex` instead of `stri_match_all_regex`

Comment: @CathG Why are you waiting?, post it as a solution :-) I really need to learn R a bit more.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks, really, because you came up with the expression to put into the function !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to go,

```
df1$pctOff10_20 <- stri_count_regex(df1$string1, '^(1\\d|20)%')
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(                        group and capture to \1:
  1                        '1'
  \d                       digits (0-9)
 |                        OR
  20                       '20'
)                        end of \1
%                        '%'
```

Comment: it's ok, earned too much of reps for today. It's time to help others.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `strapply` in gsubfn can do that by combining a regex (`pattern=` argument) and a function (`FUN=` argument). Below we use the formula representation of the function.  Alternately we could make use of `betweeen` from data.table (or a number of other packages).  This extracts the matches to the pattern, applies the function to it and returns the result simplifying it into a vector (rather than a list):

```
library(gsubfn)

btwn <- function(x, a, b) as.numeric(a <= as.numeric(x) & as.numeric(x) <= b)

transform(df1, pctOff10_20 = 
   strapply(
      X = string1, 
      pattern = "\\d+", 
      FUN = ~ btwn(x, 10, 20),
      simplify = TRUE
   )
)
```

**2)** A base solution using the same `btwn` function defined above is:

```
transform(df1, pctOff10_20 = btwn(gsub("\\D", "", string1), 10, 20))
```